# Elegant Themes – Background image in Divi theme zooms in on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a normal section module and have an image as the background of that module. It looks fine on a desktop but when viewed on a mobile device the bg is zoomed in and looks terrible. I can't seem to figure out why the mobile is not adjusting or if there is something I need to do so that the image is mobile friendly? Here is the test website http://test.mutualmind.com and the problem I'm having is worth he last section right before the footer. You can compare the desktop view vs the mobile view t see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `background-size` of that section is set to `cover` which means the background image will scale up until it fills both the width and the height of the container. In this case, your height is so large that the image must scale up to fit. If you trim some of the height off of the section on smaller devices, you'll see your image scale down along with it.

You can do this by giving the section a custom class or id on the page builder and then targeting it on smaller screens through media queries in your stylesheet.